# Assign result of a command to variables, but don't wait for the command to finish

Tags: bash, ssh, parallelism

I am trying to parallelize a bash script that looks like this:

```
var01=$(ssh $USER@host01 'bash -s' < ./node.sh) &
var02=$(ssh $USER@host02 'bash -s' < ./node.sh) &
var03=$(ssh $USER@host03 'bash -s' < ./node.sh) &
wait
echo $var01
echo $var02
echo $var03
```

Maybe you see what I am trying to do here: run the first three commands in parallel, then wait for all to finish, and lastly print the output in an ordered fashion.
But it does not seem to work like that. This script prints three empty lines, whereas without the ampersands, I get the correct output. It just takes much longer, because the commands are executed in serial.

Comment: You need to attach a dedicated file descriptor to get async process output. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017805/bash-capture-output-of-command-run-in-background

Comment: I somehow don't manage to work out the solution to my problem based on the alleged duplicates, or the link in the comment. I guess I should stick to easier stuff.

Comment: if you can't sort it out as a possibile "hack" you could make 3 different scripts and call them from main script. eg. mainscript.sh calls script1.sh& script2.sh& script3.sh&. each script[X].sh would contain var[x]=$(...) and echo below.

Comment: I don't think I can have sorted output this way

Comment: This is exactly what `parset` does: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parset.html